# Google Tag Manager and Data Layer under the hood

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, google-ads, google-tag-manager, tag-manager

I am really newbie in all this marketing stuff, so I understand everything much better on the software layer. Phrases like : "Add this script to your page directly after body tag and it will work" confuse me.
So I want to get understanding of `GTM and Data Layer`
Here are most important questions for me.
This is how I understand this stuff.

1. As far as I know, `GTM` is just piece of `JavaScript` code loaded with the page, it is useful because as I can guess this part of the code provided by `Tag Manager Account` ( I will use `GTM_JS` name for it) is used to send request to the `Google Tag Manager` server, it contains your credentials and retrieves information set up in your personal GTM account like `tag`.`GTM_JS` After retrieving information from the server, for instance piece of `HTML and JS code` like `Google Analytics`  inserts it in the `DOM`. The same if you add required code `Google Analytics` manually. And it works the same, but the benefit here is that you can dynamically include any code without editing `sources of your template or php files`, only `GTM_JS` is required.
2. What is exactly `Data Layer` is. I understand that this is just an array of data you need to pass somewhere. I can only guess that while `GTM_JS` is loaded it checks `dataLayer` variable if it contains any information, if so send it to the `GTM Server`, GTM Server in turn checks all your `Macros` and `Regex` (I don't know all features of GTM), and parses `dataLayer` variable, only after that it starts processing all created tags, because, some `tags` code may contain macro definition like `{{product_price}}` and if it finds such definition it inserts in output `tag code` specific variable.
3. After that GTM Server does some other stuff and returns just simple `HTML` code as a response to `GTM_JS`, and than this code is added to the DOM.

And questions

1. Why I cannot find `tag source` code in Page Source, but it works ? Is it hidden somehow ?
2. As I can guess, data pushed to the data layer, should be generated firstly with server side script like `php,ruby,python`, for example `User id` is available only while generating output HTML in some `Php session variable` and you need output like `<script> var dataLayer.userId = $user_id;</script>` (pseudocode). So why I cannot dynamically use my generated variable without `dataLayer`, just to specify it in desired script code inserted to the page (the same as for dataLayer) ? What is the benefit of using `DataLayer` than ?

I would be grateful for any response. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) The tag source is included at runtime from GTM_JS.   You won't be able to see it, just the GTM snippet.

2) You are correct that you could go ahead and use the variable in your page.   Where the magic happens in GTM is when you need a variable in one of your tags.   For example, I set a user's status (logged in or anonymous) as a Custom Dimension in Google Analytics.   The only way to pass this status is through the data layer.